# django oscar send_email result in ValueError: EMAIL_USE_TLS/EMAIL_USE_SSL are mutually exclusive,

Tags: django, django-oscar

This function trigger an error that doesn't make sense to me:

```
File "/venv/virtualenvs/ZHR-f7z/oscar/apps/communication/utils.py", line 128, in send_email_messages
email.send()
```

in the settings:

```
EMAIL_USE_SSL = None #False doesn't change result
EMAIL_USE_TLS = None
```

Someting wrong is happening as both are None so these can't be True:

```
File "/venv/virtualenvs/ZHR-f7z/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 31, in __init__
        self.use_ssl = settings.EMAIL_USE_SSL if use_ssl is None else use_ssl
        self.timeout = settings.EMAIL_TIMEOUT if timeout is None else timeout
        self.ssl_keyfile = settings.EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE if ssl_keyfile is None else ssl_keyfile
        self.ssl_certfile = settings.EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE if ssl_certfile is None else ssl_certfile
        if self.use_ssl and self.use_tls:
            raise ValueError(
                "EMAIL_USE_TLS/EMAIL_USE_SSL are mutually exclusive, so only set "
                "one of those settings to True.")
        self.connection = None
        self._lock = threading.RLock()



[console ready]
>>> use_ssl
>>> self.use_ssl
'None'
>>> self.use_tls
'None'
>>>
```

If I start a shell with:

```
>>> from django.core import mail
>>> mail.send_mail(
...             'Subject here', 'Here is the message.',
...             'mailfrom', ['mailto'],
...             fail_silently=False,
...         )
```

result in a success.

Any advice as the settings are both false and the ValueError should be trigger if both are True?

Thanks, BR

Answer (score 2):

`EMAIL_USE_TLS` and `EMAIL_USE_SSL` are mutually exclusive
You should choose which secure connection to use, **depending on you email provider**.

In Django EMAIL_USE_TLS uses port 587 by default, where and EMAIL_USE_SSL uses port 465 instead

So, correct setting must be

```
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

or

```
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

see [Django Doc on settings `EMAIL_USE_TLS/EMAIL_USE_SSL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-EMAIL_USE_SSL)

Comment: thanks for the answer I've tried with TLS enabled but still ends in the same ValueError: [console ready]
>>> self.use_ssl 
'True'
>>> self.use_tls
'False'
ValueError: EMAIL_USE_TLS/EMAIL_USE_SSL are mutually exclusive, so only set one of those settings to True.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I'mg a little confused, the TLS is True and the SSL is False, condition to trigger the ValueErrror means:

```
if self.use_ssl==True and self.use_tls == True
```

I would expect that both as True are needed to trigger the Exception.
But here is triggered while only one is True.

Or I'm missing something else?

Comment: I am encountering the same issue - has anyone figured out why we see this error and how to correct it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this issue, even though you already assign these settings into settings.py, for an example:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

Then to fix it just remove the setting you overriden as False from the settings.py (for me it's this code):

```
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

Then move EMAIL_USE_TLS to the top above EMAIL_HOST if you have the settings like the example i gave you.

IDK why the solution above fix the problem, maybe this is the newest bug from the django itself (i use django version 4.2.4)